# Round-robin algorithm to account for how many time a player plays first?

Tags: python, function, round-robin, tournament

I'm quite familiar with how round robin works, now I'm trying to implement a function (Python works fine) to create round-robin matchings accounting for **how many times during the tournament a player plays first**.

Ideally, I would like to have everybody begin the same (±1 if even players) number of turns and have the function telling me that, without me making the adjustments manually.

Edit: this is my attempt so far, creating a discriminant to "randomize" somehow the first player, but in doesn't work in general

```
import random

def get_rr_rounds(players):
    """
    players = ["Player1", "Player2", "Player3","Player4", "Player5", "Player6"]
    """
    if len(players) % 2:
        players.append('DUMMY')

    n = len(players)

    matchs = []
    rounds = []

    discriminant = random.choice([0, 1])

    for round in range(1, n):
        for i in range(n//2):
            if (round % 2 == discriminant):
                matchs.append((players[i], players[n - 1 - i]))
            else:
                matchs.append((players[n - 1 - i], players[i]))
        players.insert(1, players.pop())
        rounds.append(matchs)
        matchs = []
    return rounds
```

Comment: Can you add draft code or show where you are having a problem ? StackOverflow is not for getting your homework done by others.

Comment: Sorry, just added my code

Comment: One year later: did you succeed?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is round-robin, everybody plays against everybody, so the round-robin algorithm that decides the order of the matches can be independent from the function that determines whether player `i` or player `j` starts when `i` plays against `j`.

So, just paint the table you use for results in a checkerboard pattern:

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5
0    <  ^  <  ^  <
1 ^     <  ^  <  ^
2 <  ^     <  ^  <
3 ^  <  ^     <  ^
4 <  ^  <  ^     <
5 ^  <  ^  <  ^
```

Here the arrow points to the start player. This means that 0 starts when playing against 1, but is second when playing against 2, etc.

Turning this into an arithmetic formula:

#### When `i` plays against `j`, if `i < j`, then `i` starts iff `j-i` is odd.

(Note: you can replace `j-i` with `i+j` in the above formula if you want; because `+i` and `-i` have the same parity.)